# How to show omniture clickmap on button click?

Tags: adobe-analytics

In adobe site catalyst, I can see clickmap info in the resultant page ( of course in adobe debugger)  when a link is clicked. Like below:

---

Page ID (ClickMap)  http://www.test.com/my-tools.html

Page ID Type (ClickMap) 1

Object ID (ClickMap)    http://www.test.com/my-tools.html?CatPath=All%2BProducts%252F%252F%252F%252FPower%2BTool

Object Tag (ClickMap)   A

Query String End    1

---

But when I click a form button, such clickmap info is not populated into adobe debugger.I want to populate such click map info when a button is clicked.

Please suggest!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use s_objectID [s_objectID](http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/sc/implement/s_objectID.html), which sets the unique identifier for ClickMap. If the form button doesn't trigger a new page, you'll also want to fire [an s.tl() image request](http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/sc/implement/function_tl.html), which sends that information to Adobe Analytics servers without generating another page view. If the button does trigger a new page, the data will be sent in the image request on the new page.

Comment: Yes I have called s.t1() on button click event, it shows other variables and events but not clickmap.

Answer (score 0):

I just come across the solution. The solution is to move s_code.js file from head to body. Detail goes here:
http://deepakbhatta.com/omniture-clickmap-info-is-not-showing-in-button-click/